# Executing Stored Procedure - Oracle PL SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I'm currently trying to execute a stored procedure in Oracle PL SQL. I keep running into the same error for the below with execution.

I've tried both execution with the same error
       SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
       EXEC get_phone(200.00,500.00);

OR

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
   DECLARE
   c_minprice products.price%type;
   c_maxprice products.price%type;
  BEGIN
   c_minprice := get_phone(200);
   c_maxprice := get_phone(500);
  END;


 ERROR from executing the above:
c_minprice := get_phone(200);
              *

ERROR at line 5: 
 ORA-06550: line 5, column 15: 
 PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_PHONE' 
 ORA-06550: line 5, column 1: 
 PL/SQL: Statement ignored 
 ORA-06550: line 6, column 15: 
 PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_PHONE' 
 ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: 
 PL/SQL: Statement ignored 

  ****Sample Snip-its form my code:

   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_phone
   (
    c_minprice IN products.price%type,  
    c_maxprice IN products.price%type,  
    i_result OUT VARCHAR2 
  ) AS

--Checking if starting price range is valid or not
IF c_minprice IS NULL THEN
   i_result := 'Starting price range should be valid and cannot be empty';
  RAISE V_MINPRICE; -- Raising exception if starting price is null
END IF;

 --Checking if end price range is valid or not
IF c_maxprice IS NULL THEN
  i_result := 'End price range should be valid and cannot be empty';
  RAISE V_MAXPRICE; -- Raising exception if end price is null
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure requires three parameters so you have to pass in three parameters

```
DECLARE
  l_result varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  get_phone( 200, 500, l_result );
END;
/
```

should work.  Of course, your procedure seems rather pointless.  And if the goal is simply to return a result, you really ought to be using a function rather than a procedure with an `out` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Justin. This worked...I do agree with you. I may look into using a function for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

get_phone expects 3 arguments, c_minprice, c_maxprice and i_result.  You are only passing it one number.  Pass it the rest of the arguments.

Comment: That's where I'm trying running into an issue --- I have added the min price and max price. Why do I need to add the result when I only want it to pring the products between the min and max price range. For instance I use I_result for the below:                                                                                                   --Checking if starting price range is valid or not
    IF c_minprice IS NULL THEN
       i_result := 'Starting price range should be valid and cannot be empty';
      RAISE V_MINPRICE; -- Raising exception if starting price is null
    END IF;

Comment: SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
   DECLARE
   c_minprice products.price%type;
   c_maxprice products.price%type;
  BEGIN
   c_minprice := get_phone(200);
   c_maxprice := get_phone(500);
  END;

Comment: Update your original post with the additional, complete information.  The comment section is not the place for code due to no formatting.

Comment: I have made the appropriate edits in my post. Thanks